# How to replace non-alphanumeric characters from a string in SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I'd like to remove all non-alphanumeric characters from a string in SPARQL.The following returns an error:

```
SELECT * WHERE {

?s ?p ?o .
BIND(REPLACE(?o, "/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", "i") AS ?o2) .

}
```

Comment: Next time, please show the error and tell us which SPARQL engine you used...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`REPLACE` only works on string literals.  `?o` is often a URI.

Also, you probably need to escape your escape character.  `\s` should be `\\s` or more simply, just .

Or, you could try using the `\W` wildcard (which should probably be `\\W` in the query).

[Try this](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT%20*%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fs%20%3Fp%20%3Fo%20.%0D%0A%23%20BIND%28REPLACE%28STR%28%3Fs%29%2C%20%22%5C%5CW%22%2C%20%22%22%2C%20%22i%22%29%20AS%20%3Fs2%29%20.%0D%0A%23%20BIND%28REPLACE%28STR%28%3Fp%29%2C%20%22%5C%5CW%22%2C%20%22%22%2C%20%22i%22%29%20AS%20%3Fp2%29%20.%0D%0ABIND%28REPLACE%28STR%28%3Fo%29%2C%20%22%5C%5CW%22%2C%20%22%22%2C%20%22i%22%29%20AS%20%3Fo2%29%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%205%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) (sample results [against the DBpedia endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+*%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo+.%0D%0A%23+BIND%28REPLACE%28STR%28%3Fs%29%2C+%22%5C%5CW%22%2C+%22%22%2C+%22i%22%29+AS+%3Fs2%29+.%0D%0A%23+BIND%28REPLACE%28STR%28%3Fp%29%2C+%22%5C%5CW%22%2C+%22%22%2C+%22i%22%29+AS+%3Fp2%29+.%0D%0ABIND%28REPLACE%28STR%28%3Fo%29%2C+%22%5C%5CW%22%2C+%22%22%2C+%22i%22%29+AS+%3Fo2%29+.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT+5%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)) --

```
SELECT *
WHERE
  {
    ?s  ?p  ?o  .
    BIND(REPLACE(STR(?o), "\\W", "", "i") AS ?o2) .
  }
LIMIT 5
```